# Is the set of natural numbers that are multiples of at least 3 numbers (including 1 and themselves) asymptotically even?

Tags: infinity, even-and-odd-functions

I was just thinking about this in my head, I am curious as to whether I am thinking about this correctly, or if there is a flaw in my thinking (especially about infinity)

My conjecture is that the set of all numbers that are multiples of at least 3 natural numbers (1, themselves, and one other number) must be asymptotically 100% even, given that odd numbers require all multiples to be odd. So as the number of multiples extends towards infinity, numbers become more and more even, and thus this set would be asymptotically 100% even. I wanted to post this question here to see if there are flaws in my thinking or if my understanding of infinity (which I know can be tricky) isn't correct

Comment: These natural numbers are also called "composite".

Comment: What does asymptotically even mean?  How about asymptotically 100% even?

Comment: @RossMillikan What I am saying with ""asymptotically" is that as the number multiples approaches infinity, nearly all composite numbers will be even (since in only takes one even multiple to make a number even) *but* there will still be odd numbers - the set will never be 100% all even numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.  As numbers get large primes get rare.  The natural density of even composites is $50\%$.  The natural density of odd composites goes to $50\%$ so the natural densities are equal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it helped me figure out the flaw in my thinking. The flaw in my thinking was this: I was thinking that for a number with 100 multiples, the probability that it was an odd number would be (.25)^99 - (1) .25 because in any multiplication both numbers must be odd for the result to be odd, and (2) ^99 because to generate the number we'd have to multiple all multiples together. I see now that (2) is a fallacy in my thinking. Thank you for helping me for figuring out where my error in thinking was!